# Keeping more values at once than there are registers in assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

This is more of a concept question. My understanding of assembly is limited and only in terms of MIPS, so excuses me if this does not apply to other assembly architectures.

Let's say someone needed a lot of values to be stored. I can't think of a situation when someone actually needs that many registers and can't store them somewhere, but let's assume a hypothetical one.

Where can you store your data?

Comment: well, you cant...you have a limited number of registers, all the other information has to live elsewhere (ram/rom) and you swap it out as needed.  you cant have too many instructions in the pipe at the same time anyway so you just have to deal with the limitations of the processor.   Some processors have dozens to hundreds of registers, you could switch to one of those.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the MIPS architecture has a stack, too. See [these notes](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/stack.html).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Using Arrays

You can use arrays. Then you can read from the array. Here is an example, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_arrays.htm.

### Using Stacks

You *should* use stacks. There is some great stuff [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/The_Stack), [or here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info). As mentioned in the comments by, Cody Gray.

Comment: *"The ECX/CX registers store referenceable values."* What does that mean? Obviously your answer is about the x86, but there is nothing particularly special about `ECX`/`CX` when it comes to the stack on x86. The only interesting thing about this register is that it is often used as a loop counter, but that has nothing to do with the stack. Were you thinking of a different register, perhaps, like the stack pointer (`ESP`/`SP`)?

Comment: No. They can be used for "indexing" values of arrays. Take a look at the example, sorry about my phrasing. I'm not entirely sure what the best sentence for this would be. However, it does work for when you need to store many values. It's actually how a compiler compiles to assembly. It reserves just enough space for the variables it needs as an array. Then has a base pointer and a pointer or indexer. This allows programs to store variables in assembly. Keep in mind this is Intel syntax in my answer.

Comment: You can (at least assuming we're talking about 32-bit code) use any register as an index. There is nothing special about `ECX`. And there sample code you linked to isn't actually using it as an indexer at all. Nor is it showing how to use the stack. It's just reading from an array of byte values. The code wouldn't work for the stack without modification; they grown top-down on x86. A C compiler would actually compile code that uses the stack, reserving space using either a `PUSH` or `SUB` instruction at the top of the routine.

Comment: I didn't know that you could use any register as an index, what I found online was different. I'm relatively new to Assembly as well, so do you mind telling me how a stack might work?

Comment: Well, it is a rather big topic. Lots of information online, of course. Like [this Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/The_Stack). I'm not sure what you found online regarding registers. Most of what I'd imagine you'd see for "index" register would be ESI and EDI, which certain instructions (in particular, the CISC string instructions) use as source and destination indexes, respectively. Lots of good tutorials on x86 assembly in the [tag:x86] tag wiki, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question. I took a look and it makes sense, now I know how to use stacks in my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130361/discussion-between-preston-hager-and-cody-gray).

Answer (score 2):

The question says "and can't store them somewhere", which I assumed meant you can't just spill them to the stack like compilers normally do with local variables when they run out of registers.

"Clever" alternatives (which you should only use in special cases where storing on the stack or in another reserved memory location):

- pack multiple values into each register.  e.g. if you know your data fits in 16 bits, you could pack four 16-bit integers into a 64-bit general-purpose integer register.  You'd need a couple registers free to manipulate your data (e.g. unpacking with shift and AND instructions and then doing something, before re-packing).
- put it into floating-point or vector registers.  (If the FP hardware doesn't fault, flush denormals to zero, or otherwise munge arbitrary bit-patterns, then just move your integer data as-is.  Don't actually do an integer->float conversion.)